# PubSub isn't acknowledging messages

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pubsub subscription (all default settings except the number of go-routines is 1000), and for some reason messages never get acknowledged, and therefore redelivered. Redelivery is taking between 1 and 2 minutes. I'm calling `message.Ack()` less than 1 second after the message is received, so I don't understand what is happening. It shouldn't be because of latency between the app and pubsub itself, because after publishing a message to the topic, the message is delivered practically immediately.

The subscription has an acknowledgement deadline of 10 seconds. I tried increasing this to 120, but the same problem still occurred. I can't think of any reason why these messages aren't being acknowledged, and therefore being redelivered.

Code for reference:

```golang
if err := pubsubSubscription(client).Receive(ctx, func(lctx context.Context, message *pubsub.Message) {
    log.Println("Received message") // occurs < 1s after publishing
    ack := message.Ack  
    if err := adapters.Handle(conn, id, gatewayAddr, message.Data); err != nil {
        log.Println("Will nack message")
        ack = message.Nack // not reached (in this context/example)
        cancel()
    }
    log.Println("Will ack message") // occurs ~200µs after message receipt
    ack()
}); err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("unable to subscribe to PubSub messages: %s", err)
}
```

To clarify, I've only published 1 message to the topic, but that callback is called every 1 or 2 minutes infinitely.

**EDIT**

This only occurs when the number of go-routines in the subscription receive settings is set to a number higher than `runtime.NumCPU()`. Is this the expected behaviour? If so, how does this work with Kubernetes (which I'm using)?

**EDIT 2 -- request for full code for reproduction**

```golang
const (
    DefaultMaxOutstandingMessages = 1000000
    DefaultMaxOutstandingBytes    = 1e9
)

func SubscribeToTables(id int) error {
    var opts []option.ClientOption
    if sa := os.Getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT"); sa != "" {
        opts = append(opts, option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(sa)))
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    projectID := os.Getenv("PROJECT_ID")
    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectID, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error creating GCP PubSub client: %s", err)
    }

    cctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    go func() {
        qch := make(chan os.Signal)
        signal.Notify(qch, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
        <-qch
        cancel()
    }()

    mch := make(chan *pubsub.Message)
    gatewayAddr := os.Getenv("GATEWAY_ADDRESS")
    conn, err := adapters.GetGatewayConn(gatewayAddr)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("unable to connect to Gateway: %s", err)
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case message := <-mch:
                if err := adapters.Handle(conn, id, gatewayAddr, message.Data); err != nil {
                    cancel()
                    return
                }
                message.Ack()
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    if err := pubsubSubscription(client).Receive(cctx, func(_ context.Context, message *pubsub.Message) {
        mch <- message
    }); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("unable to subscribe to PubSub messages: %s", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func pubsubSubscription(client *pubsub.Client) *pubsub.Subscription {
    sub := client.Subscription(os.Getenv("SUBSCRIPTION_ID"))
    sub.ReceiveSettings = pubsub.ReceiveSettings{
        MaxExtension:       pubsub.DefaultReceiveSettings.MaxExtension,
        MaxExtensionPeriod: pubsub.DefaultReceiveSettings.MaxExtensionPeriod,
        MaxOutstandingMessages: parsePubSubReceiveSetting(
            "MAX_OUTSTANDING_MESSAGES",
            "max outstanding messages",
            DefaultMaxOutstandingMessages,
        ),
        MaxOutstandingBytes: parsePubSubReceiveSetting(
            "MAX_OUTSTANDING_BYTES",
            "max outstanding bytes",
            DefaultMaxOutstandingBytes,
        ),
        NumGoroutines: parsePubSubReceiveSetting( // if this is higher than runtimie.NumCPU(), the aforementioned issue occurs 
            "NUM_GO_ROUTINES",
            "Go-routines",
            1000, 
        ),
    }
    return sub
}

func parsePubSubReceiveSetting(env, name string, defaultValue int) int {
    e := os.Getenv(env)
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(e)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Unable to parse number of GCP PubSub %s. Can't parse '%s' as int", name, e)
        log.Printf("Using default number of %s (%d)", name, defaultValue)
        return defaultValue
    }
    return i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you exit too quickly your code. You have to `cancel()` the context for stopping the `Receive` loop and flushing the data back to PubSub.

Try to add `cancel()` just after  your `ack()`

Comment: That cancels the whole subscription. Obviously I want to keep the receive function running; I just don't want to receive duplicate messages

Comment: In this case, you case reuse the [code snippet in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#concurrency_control). Your receive function simply post the message into a channel and a side goroutine wait value on the channel. You can add timeout on the context is you want also for stooping the endless loop.

Comment: Can you share a functional and minimal code for reproducing  your case?